# Adding a shortcode in theme's shortcodes.php results in error

Tags: wordpress

I have added the following code in my theme's shortcodes.php:

```
if (!function_exists('testlist')) {
    function testlist($atts, $content = null) {
        $args = shortcode_atts(array("list"=>""), $atts);
        return "Here's a test to see if the function is called.";
    }
}
add_shortcode('testlist', 'testlist');
```

When I call the shortcode (typing [testlist] in the editor), the following error occurs:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-vc-base.php on line 345

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-vc-base.php:345) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1178
```

Comment: Are you using this code in the plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-vc-base.php  If not then there is an issue with that js_composer plugin which sounds to be an editor plugin of some sort.

Comment: Contact support of support.WPBakery.com will solve your problem with js_composer